# Jquery : Appending Dynamic Controls Leads to an Issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using SSRS to display reports what i doing technically is I am dynamically adding an Anchor Tag in HTML when the reports gets rendered. Now what the issue is Its Working Properly in IE 8 but not working in rest of the other sites. I am using Jquery to add that link inside Html here is the code. Please tell me what should i do to implement the same thing in all the browsers including Safari

```
 $('#ReportViewer1_ctl01_ctl07').slice(0).append('<a>close Popup</a>');
```

IE 8 View[image]

Rest of the Browser its not working

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it.... i have used innerHTML property of Div. Below is the example code

```
document.getElementById('ReportViewer1_ctl01_ctl07').innerHTML += '<a>close Popup</a>'
```